# (CORS) How does the browser know when to do a pre-flight request

Tags: javascript, rest, dom, xmlhttprequest, cors

So I have been using CORS for a short time now, I just read up on how it works behind the scenes.

My question is how does the browser know when to do a pre-flight request?

There is no issue involved right now, as the browser seems to be working fine, I am just a little bit curious. Because when I make the request, I am not giving it any information on whether or not it is CORS, yet it still knows to do a pre-flight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser will send a preflight request if:

- You add custom headers to your request
- You use a method other than GET, HEAD or POST
- You use POST with an unusual Content-Type.

More details here: [HTTP access control (CORS), Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Comment: So I am guessing this is independent of whether it is CORS or not. This was mentioned in a video, but every single request is either simple or not simple. Simple request are those that satisfy the conditions you mentioned above. Non simple are any form of request that does not satisfy this. When the browser is making a non-simple request it will make a pre-flight response. This is a browser feature and is unrelated to CORS. Unfortunately I did not find a proper link to explain this but if anyone is reading this hope it helps!

Comment: On Firefox, a preflight request is also issued when a xhr.upload.onprogress listener is attached.